# Change a xcode View after a certain time

Tags: xcode, swift, segue, countdown

hey i want to make a reaction game in xcode with swift and i have 2 ViewControllers. The first one tells the player the task and the second one is the game. I want the first View to segue to the second one after 2 seconds but I don't know how to do that... Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I would use `NSTimer`. Something like this should wait for 2 seconds and than the selector is triggered. I am not at my XCode right now so I can't test it, but it should work.

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2.0, target: self, selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}

func update() {
    //present your view controller
}
```

Comment: What line exactly gives you this error? Could you show more code?

Comment: I fixed the problem above but now it says that:  target: self,  doesn't work because self is an unresolved identifier

Comment: Great, could you please accept my answer? It would help me a lot! Thanks!